# Face illusion in ads

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, effects

[image]

http://doityourself.edublogs.org/files/2008/10/club-med-illusion-ad.jpg

I'm trying to achieve the same effect, but I can't even get close to what I need. What I basically need is to merge face/body in to the object in a way that it won't stand out, yet would be recognisable.

If someone could explain, give a tip or just link me something, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Andrew.

Comment: It's really about understanding illustration and positive/negative space. Then, at that point, it's about posing models and photography and lighting and blending and post-processing photo editing, etc. Alas, there's no simple tip or tutorial link that will make this easy.

Answer (score 2):

The area for these kind of illustrations comes technically under something called gestalt theory - how the human brain interprets visually.

Here is some reading you can check out to better understand the concept:

- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/design-theory/the-gestalt-principle-design-theory-for-web-designers/
- http://graphicdesign.spokanefalls.edu/tutorials/process/gestaltprinciples/gestaltprinc.htm
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology

Comment: You may also wish to research Pareidolia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it using photoshop/illustrator:

I would first grab the image I want to imitate and make it b&w and as contrasting as it can be. Alternatively, I would re-draw it in simple vector shapes using maybe 3 or 4 shades of any colour, just to get an idea of how it's composed. With that simplified version, I would overlap images until I get a somehow similar outline and tone.

Would be good to see what image you are working on, but this is the approach I would probably take.